# How to test for the best colour of an online store?

Tags: color-scheme, ab-testing

I already ran a test set up as following:
I told the users what they were going to buy, showed them the same webpage in eight different colours (four webpages on two rows), and asked them on which webpage they would want to go to buy the product.
The result was that 70% clicked on the top left choice which is not the colour that I expected according to the colour theory. Therefore I think that in this setup users can't think which colour is best and they just click in the *golden triangle*.

So how should I design such test ?
*(knowing that I'll probably be using usabilityhub.com)*

Answer (score 6):

Some thoughts on the experiment are:

1. **Subjective.** Your test seems to be more like [Luscher color test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%BCscher_color_test), but bear in mind that color preferences are subjective and not permanent.
2. **Randomize.** To get the proof of the golden triangle effect just mix randomly the webpages before each test session.
3. **Bias.** You are biased experimentator, as you have some expectations on outcom. It's wrong setup.
4. **Usability metrics.** In the real word scenario users have no ability to choose color of the site. Instead they do some action in a given site. So use test to check use cases, which could be measured with objective usability metrics.
5. **Hint.** Choosing color, align it with branding (business side) and accessibility (user side).
6. **Responsibility.** You are designer. You convinced of your choice of the color. So take the responsibility and use it!

To shorten the list, leave only the last item. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the color choice will affect the conversion rate only marginally, compared to other issues like interaction, quality of images, descriptions, performance, etc. So my approach would be to follow Alexey's recommendation:

1) choose the color you see fit (obviously you have a theory-backed choice already)

2) when the site is live and analytics are accumulating, randomly choose another color and compare conversion rates per color